# In iphone, how do I obtain the city of current timezone?

Tags: ios, timezone

e.g.

I have this current value GMT+8 ..or GMT+9
how do I obtain the city name  of this timezone?

like
*GMT+8 should output "MANILA"

or
*GMT+9 should output "TOKYO"

is that possible? THANKS!

*depending on the iPhone settings located on the settings app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSTimeZone *cur = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
NSString *name = [cur name];
NSLog(@"%@",name);
```

The output will be like this:

```
Asia/Dhaka
```

For your case, construct a NSTimeZone object with your desired time zone then use this process to get the city name.

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: is there a way to get "Dhaka" instead of "Asia/Dhaka"?